# Any potential problems with these remaps?

Tags: vim

I wanted to add a way to run :noh that made the most sense to me, so I added the following

```
nnoremap / :noh<CR>/
nnoremap ? :noh<CR>?
```

So far it's working exactly how I expected (and want): hilights are cleared as another search is started and typing /<backspace> makes more sense for me than <leader><space> or similar.

My concern is that this will somehow break other useful commands or a plugin.

Anyone know if I'm safe doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What you can break in third party plugins

Every mapping that you define *can* break plugins, if they are badly written, or if they rely on mappings that you have redefined.

Consider a plugin that uses `map` instead of `noremap` or `normal` instead of `normal!`: if the right-hand side of that mapping or the normal mode commands include `/`, then your mapping will be triggered.

Still, it wo'nt break much, it's just a matter of display.

#### What you can break in a normal use of vim

But there is still a case where you break something: Try this

`iI am typing in insert mode`<kbd>CTRL-O</kbd>`/hello`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Normally, CTRL-O in insert mode temporarily switches to normal mode for one command. You've just broken that, because the call to  `:noh` consumes that command.

You still can do it this way:

```
function ResetPattern(forward)
    noh
    redraw
    return a:forward ? '/' : '?'
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> / ResetPattern(1)
nnoremap <expr> ? ResetPattern(0)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably go with a solution like remapping <BS> or <C-l>, but I appreciate the examples of where this wouldn't work and how to do it right.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's safe. But, it will lose some functionality.

For example:

- Type `/hello`<kbd>Enter</kbd> will highlight all `hello`
- Type `/world` to inc-search, then type <kbd>ESC</kbd> to return where you are. But the original highlight is lost.

---

I just have this mapping in my `.vimrc`:

```
nmap <BS> :noh<CR>
```

Comment: +1 I can't agree more. I don't like that mapping too for the very same reason.

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't used this feature much, but I can definitely see its use.

Answer (score 0):

Normal mode mapping `<C-l>` usually refreshes the screen. I have modified it to clear highlightings. Easily available and comes from a reflex nowadays. Doesn't destroy any functionality and clearing the highlights can be thought as a part of the screen refreshing.

```
nnoremap <C-l> :nohl<CR><C-l>
```